Is that possible to print a 3D model generated by AI?
I’ve been experimenting with some AI modeling tools like Meshy.ai and luma. I had the idea to print some AI-generated models for decoration. However, I’ve noticed that the details aren’t as refined as I’d like for 3D printing.
Does anyone have any tips or techniques for adjusting the details to make these models more suitable for 3D printing? Any advice on software or methods to enhance the details would be greatly appreciated!

Probably the best answer is "Wait for better models". Surely there are tips to improve the results but to make them actually good is still a generation or two of AI generators away.
